# React Native API Request slow on production but fast on development

Tags: javascript, react-native, apisauce

I'm having a huge problem where my requests take long on the production server but are quick on the development server.

I'm using apisauce to make my requests.

Slow request example:
The login screen uses a simple username and password with redux to store the logged-in user data.
This can take up to 30 seconds but on development, it takes about 2 secs.

One of the improvements I made was setting the headers only once instead of on all the requests which were not clever but are better now. There was only a slight speed improvement but not enough.
I was also using the AsyncStorage to store the user data but that is now changed to redux, again a slight improvement but not enough.

I did try and debug with react native debugger but it wouldn't connect so I did it manually with timing the requests.

Does anyone know why the requests are slower and how to fix them?

So I've done some more testing and found that the posting of an image was one of the causes to the slow request speed, not sure why it's only on the live server.

I also found on the first login when I ran the network inspection, the Waiting (TTFB) took about 18seconds then after that it's fine. I'm not sure why that is though.
[image]

Comment: do you use the same API for dev and prod environment?

Comment: No, but they both run on the same server. I redirected my react-native dev environment to the production server and it's fast but once again when its in production its slow

Comment: try making postman request to prod, probably its on standby mode when inactive, then takes time to wake

Comment: I tested it with postman and the requests are the same for both the production and the development environments. This is why I don't think it's the API but instead the app.

Comment: I found the issue, its because of the API and not the react mobile app